# Cleanest way to query for parent class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution that pleases me.

I'm working with some composite components, and I don't have full control over them, and now I have to set values to them using `JavaScript`, and I thought `JQuery` would serve me well, as it did.

What happens is that the component's `HTML` output has a structure simlar to this:

```
<span id="externalSpan">
    <span id="internalSpan">
        <input type="text" class="component-value" />
    </span>
</span>
```

So all I had to do was check the `component-value` input, and if it's empty, I set the default value to it.

I solved it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var defaultValue = $('#defaultValue').val();

    $('.component-value').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).val(defaultValue);
        }
    });

});
```

And that worked fine, but now there's a new condition I need to evaluate. If the component has the `manualInput` CSS class, I cannot set it's value, but the class is set on the `externalSpan` which is the input's *grandfather* component, and it looks like this:

```
<span id="externalSpan" class="manualInput">
    <span id="internalSpan">
        <input type="text" class="component-value" />
    </span>
</span>
```

The simplest way that I found to do it was this:

```
if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('manualInput')){ ... }
```

And it works, but it seems really smelly to me, another solution was to invoke `parents()` with a class selector and check the `length`, but it seems odd too.

Is there a cleaner way for me to do this? And if not, which of the 2 options described above is a better solution?

Comment: If the external and internal span don't have an identifier, do make sure to mention that; it certainly confused me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So add the check to the selector

```
$('span:not(.manualInput) > span > .component-value').each(function(){
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJxhX/)

Comment: This won't work _as is_ because the `internalSpan` will fall into that, and it doesn't have any class, but I think I can modify it for my needs

Comment: What do you mean the internal span would fall into that?

Comment: the `#internalSpan` element is a span element that is not `.manualInput`, so even on elements with ancestors that are `.manualInput` the `.component-value` element will still be selected.

Comment: So make it more specific `span:not(.manualInput) > span > .component-value`

Comment: @epascarello, i think `.component-value:not(.manualInput .component-value)` would be a bit more elegant.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Probably a good bit slower though. That's not a standard selector, and it needs to do much more traversal. Though it would be a little more resilient against breakage due to DOM changes.

Comment: @zzzzBov looks very elegant indeed, I don't need to worry much about performance in this case, although the solutions using `closest` seem to be easier for other devs in the team to read.

Comment: But you also need to weigh in the "cost" of doing a loop and looking at the parents on every iteration.

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki: If you do move it all to the selector, then you can simplify things a bit like this: `$(...selector...).val(function(i, val) { return val || defaultValue });`

Comment: @CrazyTrain I liked your solution, it even removes an `if` to check for empty values, I'm accepting this answer as the right one. The comments were really helpful. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @CrazyTrain, Is selector speed a legitimate concern in this case? I certainly agree that it's likely to be slower, but for a language such as JavaScript where much of the code is run asynchronously and the browser spends most of its time idling, selector speed tends to not be an issue unless it's being used in a callback that fires rapidly.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Could be. I don't know. Bigger issue IMO is that it's not a standard selector. It's just locks you down that much more to a proprietary API.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, I hardly consider jQuery's API to be "proprietary" given its license.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Oh, you want to quibble over my use of that word. Fine, I should have said non-native. Point is the same. jQuery fixes deviations from standards by introducing its own deviations. Some are more blatant, like invalid Selectors API selectors, but others are more subtle, like introducing small variations on how native code would work.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, While I'm interested in continuing this conversation, comments are not the place. Please feel free to shoot me an email.

Answer (score 1):

A much better solution, use a selector that avoids `.component-value` elements that are descendants of `.manualInput`:

```
$('.component-value:not(.manualInput .component-value)').each(...)
```

---

Ideally the grandparent element would have a consistent class such that you could call [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
if ($(this).closest('.component-value-grandfather').hasClass('manualInput')) {...}
```

Alternatively you could check to see if there is a `.manualInput` ancestor at all:

```
if ($(this).closest('.manualInput').length) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, @zzzzBov, your suggestions were of great value to me

Answer (score 1):

I would use `closest` :

```
if(!$(this).closest('#externalSpan').hasClass('manualInput')){ ... }
```

Source : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this --

```
if($(this).closest('.manualInput').length > 0){ 
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following

```
$('span:not(.manualInput) > span').find('.component-value:empty').each(function () {
    $(this).val(defaultValue);
});
```

Or better yet,

```
$('.component-value:empty', 'span:not(.manualInput) > span').val(defaultValue);
```

Probably, the shorted piece of code to achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use

```
if ($(this).parents('.manualInput').length) {/*...*/}
```

See jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). I suppose this is the shortest way to find the parent(s) of a given element